# Do Status Effects End In Mansions of Madness?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

We played *Mansions of Madness* for the first time this weekend and I was surprised that fire was so devastating.

When a status effect is placed in a room, like fire, does it ever end without an 'action'?

Comment: "I was surprised that fire was so devastating" - I'm sure that's also been said outside of a boardgaming context. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** The keyword in the rules (found [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf)) is "ongoing." Status effects do not end until an action is taken to end them.